# How to set a default value for a method call in a instance with minitest?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, minitest

I am learning ruby and TDD. I am using Minitest as my unit test framework.
Currently I have a class (pair) that will be initialized with two instances of a second class (participant). To unit test it, I would like to create two mocks of participants and pass them to the initialize method:

```
def test_init
    participantOne = Minitest::Mock.new
    participantOne.expect(:name, "P1")
    participantOne.expect(:dept, "D1")

    participantTwo = Minitest::Mock.new
    participantTwo.expect(:name, "P2")
    participantTwo.expect(:dept, "D2")

    pair = Pair.new(participantOne, participantTwo)

    assert_equal("P1", pair.participantOne.name) #I would like to change this line
    assert_equal("P2", pair.participantTwo.name) # and this line


end
```

This works, but it is not 100% correct.
If I change the assert equal line to

```
assert_equal(participantOne.name, pair.participantOne.name) #I would like to change this line
```

To compare the value of the stored participant with the value of the mock (which I would like to store), I get

> MockExpectationError: No more expects available for :name: []

To be honest, I don't really understand it. It seems that the "expect" I set before was already "used" during the execution of my code.

This is not exactly what I am looking for. I do not want to verify how many times a method is called, I would like to define a default value to be returned when the method is called in a given instance.

**How can I do that using minitest?**

I made some search and I read about stubs in Minitest. But as far as I understood they are meant to stub a method call for every instance of a class.

I would like to create two participants and define their name and dept information, without using the real class, so I can focus my test in the subject under test.

ps:
this is the init in my pair class

```
def initialize(participantOne, participantTwo)
    @participantOne = participantOne
    @participantTwo = participantTwo
end
```

and participant class

```
def initialize(name, dept)
    @name=name
    @dept=dept
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close to correct.

Minitest provides mocks and stubs:

- Use a mock when you want to verify which method calls will be called, and how many times.
- Use a stub when you want a placeholder, such as an object with a method that always returns the same value.

What you're trying to test first is if your Pair.new sets the objects correctly.

You don't need a mock, and you don't need a stub; you can use a plain old Ruby object.

```
p1 = Object.new
p2 = Object.new
pair = Pair.new(p1, p2)
assert_equal(p1, pair.participant1)
assert_equal(p2, pair.participant2)
```

Suppose you decide to add some complex Pair initialization code, and then you want to test that the initialization code doesn't accidentally change the participants' names and descriptions.

You don't need mocks, and you don't need stubs; you can use plain old Ruby objects.

```
p1name = "p1n"
p1desc = "p1d"
p1 = Participant.new(p1name, p1desc)

p2name = "p2n"
p2desc = "p2d"
p2 = Participant.new(p2name, p2desc)

pair = Pair.new(p1, p2)

assert_equal(p1name, pair.participantOne.name)
assert_equal(p1desc, pair.participantOne.desc)
assert_equal(p2name, pair.participantTwo.name)
assert_equal(p2desc, pair.participantTwo.desc)
```

All of the above are plain old Ruby objects, not mocks nor stubs.

The reason you would switch from plain old Ruby objects to mocks or stubs is if you want to explicitly test which methods are called (so use a mock) or the setup is more complex, or time consuming (so use a stub).

Comment: great, thanks! I am not used to the ruby "way of thinking", so I would never  notice that I can just change Participant for Object. I just have one question regarding the second approach (the one you create real Participants): Changes in the participant class could cause this test to break, and I would like to avoid this. Is there any way I can do that?

Comment: You asked "Changes in the participant class could cause this test to break, and I would like to avoid this. Is there any way I can do that?" Yes, of course it depends on what you're changing. Evolve your tests as you evolve your needs. You can use unit tests (such as these) and also use functional tests, and integration tests.